# npm-wp-s-theme domain.enter is not a function error

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

when I go `yo npm-wp-s-theme` I get the error domain.enter is not a function error

versions:

- yo 4.3.1
- npm 9.7.2
- node 20.4.0
- macOS terminal